# pass html TextBox Value from User control to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I am creating a user control where in i have different HTML text boxes and for items like name profession contact etc. 
i have a edit and save button for each item. so when i click on the save button i want the value of that text box and update the same in the database .  So for this i want to send that value to the ASPX page. but i don't know how to send that value to the ASPX.Also if there is another way to achieve this them please suggest.I am using the three tier architecture.

Thankx

Comment: do you have asp.net textbox or html textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If text box is asp text box  or html runat="server" st than you need to expose textbox value as property

```
public string textData
{
 get { return mytextbox.Text; }
 set { mytextbox.Text = value; }
}
```

**OR**

If you text box is html than make use of `Request.QueryString["textboxnameorid"] will` provide you data on postback.

Comment: Thankx But I am using HTML text "<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="user_name" style="display:none;" value = "Santosh"/>"

Comment: @Santosh Sahu - make use of request.querystring collection to get the value.............but not sure because your style is dispaly non

Answer (score 0):

if you are using asp.net textbox, you can create public properties in you usercontrol like this

```
public string Name
        {
            get { return tbName.Text; }
            set { tbName.Text = value; }
        }
```

and this public property can be get set in asp.net page easily..

Regards.

Comment: you will have to place runat="server" or use asp.net textbox if you want to access them on aspx codebehind